# How to find the words starting after line breaks, using regex, Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string, consisting of several lines, e.g.:

```
When I was younger
I never needed
And I was always OK
but it was a long Time Ago
```

The problem is to invert first letters of all the words which length is more than 3. That is an output must be the following:

```
when I Was Younger
I Never Needed
and I Was Always OK
But it Was a Long time ago
```

There is my code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Part3_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "When I was younger\r\nI never needed\r\nAnd I was always OK\r\nbut it was a long Time Ago";
        System.out.println(convert(str));
}

    public static String convert(String str) {
        String result = "";
        String[] strings = str.split(" ");
        String regexLowerCase = "\\b[a-z]{3,}\\b";
        String regexLowerCaseInitial = "(\\r\\n)[a-z]{3,}\\b";
        String regexUpperCase = "\\b([A-Z][a-z]{2,})+\\b";
        String regexUpperCaseInitial = "(\\r\\n)([A-Z][a-z]{2,})\\b";
        Pattern patternLowerCase = Pattern.compile(regexLowerCase, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Pattern patternUpperCase = Pattern.compile(regexUpperCase, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Pattern patternLowerCaseInitial = Pattern.compile(regexLowerCaseInitial, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Pattern patternUpperCaseInitial = Pattern.compile(regexUpperCaseInitial, Pattern.MULTILINE);

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            Matcher matcherLowerCase = patternLowerCase.matcher(strings[i]);
            Matcher matcherUpperCase = patternUpperCase.matcher(strings[i]);
            Matcher matcherLowerCaseInitial = patternLowerCaseInitial.matcher(strings[i]);
            Matcher matcherUpperCaseInitial = patternUpperCaseInitial.matcher(strings[i]);
            char[] words = strings[i].toCharArray();
            if (matcherLowerCase.find() || matcherLowerCaseInitial.find()) {
                char temp = Character.toUpperCase(words[0]);
                words[0] = temp;
                result += new String(words);
            } else if (matcherUpperCase.find() || matcherUpperCaseInitial.find()) {
                char temp = Character.toLowerCase(words[0]);
                words[0] = temp;
                result += new String(words);
            } else {
                result += new String(words);
            }

            if (i < strings.length - 1) { 
                result += " "; 
            } 
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here:

- `"\\b[a-z]{3,}\\b"` is a regular expression, selecting all words in lower case which length is 3 or more symbols,
- `"\\b([A-Z][a-z]{2,})+\\b"` is a regular expression, selecting all words starting from capital letter which length is 3 or more symbols.

Both regular expressions works properly but when we have a line breaks - they do not work. The output of my program execution is following:

```
when I Was Younger
I Never Needed
And I Was Always OK
but it Was a Long Time ago
```

As I understood, these regular expressions cannot select words `And` and `but` from `needed\r\nAnd` and `OK\r\nbut` respectively.

To fix this bug I tried to add new regular expressions `"(\\r\\n)[a-z]{3,}\\b"` and `"(\\r\\n)([A-Z][a-z]{2,})\\b"`, but they do not work.

How to compose the regular expressions, selecting words after line breaks?

Comment: Look [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1029878/182013).. Also, instead of `\\r\\n`, use `\\R`. Or, to match at the start of a line use `^` and pass `re.MULTILINE` flag.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to split the string on a word break (`\b`) instead, and then pass the white space through to the final string in the `strings` array. This removes the need to have separate regex for the different situations, and also the need to add back space characters. This will give you the results you want:

```
public static String convert(String str) {
    String result = "";
    String[] strings = str.split("\\b");
    String regexLowerCase = "^[a-z]{3,}";
    String regexUpperCase = "^[A-Z][a-z]{2,}+";
    Pattern patternLowerCase = Pattern.compile(regexLowerCase, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Pattern patternUpperCase = Pattern.compile(regexUpperCase, Pattern.MULTILINE);

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        Matcher matcherLowerCase = patternLowerCase.matcher(strings[i]);
        Matcher matcherUpperCase = patternUpperCase.matcher(strings[i]);
        char[] words = strings[i].toCharArray();
        if (matcherLowerCase.find()) {
            char temp = Character.toUpperCase(words[0]);
            words[0] = temp;
            result += new String(words);
        } else if (matcherUpperCase.find()) {
            char temp = Character.toLowerCase(words[0]);
            words[0] = temp;
            result += new String(words);
        } else {
            result += new String(words);
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
when I Was Younger
I Never Needed
and I Was Always OK
But it Was a Long time ago
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/JRPWZ57071)